# How to add code behind file for home.aspx?

Tags: 2010, aspx, codebehind

I want to add a code behind file to check the user's group. But I cannot find the code behind file for home.aspx. How can I create one?

Answer (score 0):

`.cs` file types are not visible for SharePoint pages/pagelayouts.

In order for you to add your own to one of the Out-of-the-box pages like Home.aspx you'll have to

- Create a new .cs file in Visual Studio which derives from either `Page` or `WebPartPage`

Example:

```
public class MyCustomCodeBehindForHomeAspx : Page
```

- Then you have to open Home.aspx in e.g. SharePoint Designer and add the fully qualified name

Example:

```
<%@ Page 
    Language="C#" 
    DynamicMasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" 
    Inherits="MyNamspace.MyCustomCodeBehindForHomeAspx, fully qualified assembly name here"
    %>
```

Comment: Do I have to write "MyNamspace" or the namespace my .cs file is in? @Daniel Ziga

Comment: @ABeginner Namespace of your .cs file

Comment: It is throwing me this error : Could not load the assembly '$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$'. Make sure that it is compiled before accessing the page. @Daniel Ziga

Comment: Replace `$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$` with your dll's info

Comment: On using gacutil command it says 0 items exist in global assembly cache for mynameapace

Comment: How to know whether assembly is getting generated? @Daniel Ziga